# ajax search with input field

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to create a ajax function to just reload a `<div>` and not the entire page.

What is working:
-during writing in the input field the div is reloaded after every character correctly.

What is not working:
-when the input field is complete empty again, it is not showing the whole entries I have in the database.

this is what I have in the php file where the div is:

```
function showGames(str) {
if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("searchgame").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else { 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET","searchgame.php?game="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
} }
```

this is what I have in the search.php

```
<?php

include 'test/database.php';

$pdo = Database::connect();

if($_GET['game'] == "") {
    $sql="SELECT * FROM games WHERE active=1";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Should be empty')</script>";

} else {
    $q = $_GET['game'];
    $sql="SELECT * FROM games WHERE gamenamelong LIKE '%".$q."%'";
}

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute();
$gameResults = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$rowCount1 = count($gameResults);
```

Is anybody able to help me? 
Thank you!

Comment: it's because of your 3rd line! You are emtying the div when the searchstring is empty, and dont hit the ajax

Comment: Hoi Jeff, even when i am modifying the 3rd line it's not working after emptying the input field.

Answer (score 0):

since we don't know how your form looks like, and what calls the function `showGames` how, I can only give a vague answer. But your main problem/misstake should be solved with that:

In your function `showGames` you never hit the ajax if the search string is empty, so you can't get back *all* results.

So I suggest to change that function like so:

```
function showGames(str) {
   if (str == "") {
      document.getElementById("searchgame").innerHTML = "";
      //remove that: return;
   } 
   // remove the 'else { '

   // now you allways hit the ajax
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

    }
  };

  xmlhttp.open("GET","searchgame.php?game="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
// remove closing bracket of if-else: '}'
}
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks again for the help. i removed it and still it's not working properly. This is the form i am using: <form>
     <input name="searchgame" onkeydown="showGames(this.value)" type="text" class="form-control hidden-xs" placeholder="Search Game...">
     </form> ... The strange behavior i saw it that when i put it the first letter its not transmitted directly to the php file. after putting in the second letter i can see that the first letter was transmitted. hope you can follow?